# Bed heating stops when paused by filament runout sensor

Tags: heated-bed, adhesion, fdm, creality-cr-10, filament-sensor

My CR-10 S5 has a feature, that stops the print, when the filament runs out.

However, when the printer pauses, the bed cools down and the print plops if the bed. Is there a way to tell the printer to keep the bed heated, when paused (by the runout detector)?

Comment: unless you write custom firmware? No.

Comment: Has this to to with the "economic" mode? If so, you have your [answer here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/8425/). I don't know if this reflects recent firmware versions.

Comment: @0scar nope, that is part of the Filament runout sensor alarm code, not the eco mode

Comment: Does it cool down immediately or is it a separate heater timeout after the pause?

Answer (score 1):

## There is no easy way to keep the bed heated during pause

Looking at the sourcecode, I am pretty sure that the current version (10/29/2019) keeps the heated bed at the right temperature.
Features are built into the firmware. You need an Arduino and some wires to write new firmware to the built-in SOC. Adjusting the code should be as simple as commenting a single line.

That is some serious shortcoming of the CR-10 S5! I can't imagine a reason why not to leave the heated bed on.

The command that keeps the heated bed at temperature is in Marlin_main.cpp:5664:
[Source code link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/134SwAcHc2dytvZLdfni10s3DteeAkMlL)

Comment: which line would that be?

Answer (score 1):

## It's in the firmware

Filament runout sensors generally trigger `M600`. **Usually** that preserves the bed temperature, but some firmware distributions might have this set up wrong.

## How is M600 working?

The firmware dictates what is done in case of filament runout. The standard settings in [`configuration.h`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/configuration/configuration.html) can look like this:

```
//#define FILAMENT_RUNOUT_SENSOR
#if ENABLED(FILAMENT_RUNOUT_SENSOR)
  #define NUM_RUNOUT_SENSORS   1     // Number of sensors, up to one per extruder. Define a FIL_RUNOUT#_PIN for each.
  #define FIL_RUNOUT_INVERTING false // Set to true to invert the logic of the sensor.
  #define FIL_RUNOUT_PULLUP          // Use internal pullup for filament runout pins.
  //#define FIL_RUNOUT_PULLDOWN      // Use internal pulldown for filament runout pins.

  // Set one or more commands to execute on filament runout.
  // (After 'M412 H' Marlin will ask the host to handle the process.)
  #define FILAMENT_RUNOUT_SCRIPT "M600"

  // After a runout is detected, continue printing this length of filament
  // before executing the runout script. Useful for a sensor at the end of
  // a feed tube. Requires 4 bytes SRAM per sensor, plus 4 bytes overhead.
  //#define FILAMENT_RUNOUT_DISTANCE_MM 25

  #ifdef FILAMENT_RUNOUT_DISTANCE_MM
    // Enable this option to use an encoder disc that toggles the runout pin
    // as the filament moves. (Be sure to set FILAMENT_RUNOUT_DISTANCE_MM
    // large enough to avoid false positives.)
    //#define FILAMENT_MOTION_SENSOR
  #endif
#endif
```

So, we need to see what [`M600`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M600.html) does. M600 is configured in some way:

> The settings for this command can be found in Configuration_adv.h.

So, you need to reconfigure how M600 behaves... [Here's how to properly do it in 1.1.8/1.1.9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwHpXaj_6xE&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=TeachingTech) and [how does it actually work in the first place in 2.0?](https://crosslink.io/2020/07/17/marlin-2-0-m600-filament-change-setup-explained/):

First, make sure the line `#define ADVANCED_PAUSE_FEATURE` has no leading `//` in `configuration_adv.h`.

Make sure you have `#define FILAMENT_RUNOUT_SENSOR` uncommented with no leading `//` in `configuration.h`. Typically, it just calls `M600`. You can replace the line with any other line of commands, for example have it play music or abort the print, or just dwell for a couple minutes and beep tragically. The factory setup for M600 contains safety setup: "if not attended in time - shut down. This includes shutting down the heated bed."

But where is the actual M600 defined? Oh, that's sneakily hidden in `Marlin_main.ccp` for 1.1.9... and oddly enough it does **not** call to turn off the heated bed unless it goes into *did nothing cooldown*.

Comment: This has no reference to the heated bed, so, does the newest firmware version doesn't drop the bed temperature on pause? 
(Note `M600` is a multi purpose pause and filament change script, it doesn't reference bed temperature) Also, does Marlin 2.0.x has a `Marlin_main.cpp`?

Comment: @0scar which is what *stumps* me - there *shouldn't* be a shutdown, unless it is in the distribution OP installed.

Comment: I checked the current version (2.0) and there in the M600 command, the manage_heater is called, which in turn keeps the bed temperature. I'm pretty sure op has an older firmware where this is not fixed.